# Need to understand and calculate probability distribution question (binomial distribution)

Tags: probability

Given: probability of HIV infection in population is 6%. We have 200 random samples with a size of n = 10. Now I have to calculate few questions and I need help to understand what exactly have been asked.

A: Calculate for each sample the point estimation of the proportion and the confidence interval of 95%.

B: How many confidence intervals would you expect that would contain the real parameter of p=0.06 and how many really have it?

C: Make a histogram with the observed values and overlap with a theoretical normal curve that would be expected according to the Central Theorem of limit. I can genereate this, but would like to understand what does that mean.

D: you want to study the prevalence of the HIV in the population that visits “Swinger clubs”. What would be the necessary size to obtain a precision estimate of 2%?

Comment: On this site, you need to show what you've tried or where you're confused. If you have no idea where to start, start by reading the wikipeidia articles on confidence intervals and binomial distributions.

Comment: A) the second half about confidence intervals means $P( a<X<b)=.95$,  where X is bin(10,.06). For continuous distributions this makes sense, but for discrete ones it's a bit more complicated. The mean is .6, so I'd calculate it with a=0 and b=1 to start. For c) look up the central limit theorem.